# Unable to switch control to a prompt with multiple fields in selenium

Tags: selenium, selenium-webdriver

I am trying to select an element in the prompt, but I am unable to switch control to the prompt.

I've tried the below code:

```
Alert a = driver.switchTo().alert();
WebElement e = wait.until(Expected Conditions.visibilityofElementLocated(By.xpath("locator"));
```

Adding HTML code

```
<table role="dialog" aria-labelledby="ariaLabelledBy_promptsDlg" oncontextmenu="_CWprompts.eventCancelBubble(event);return false" border="0" cellspacing="0" cellpadding="0" id="promptsDlg" style="display: block; padding: 0px; visibility: visible; position: absolute; top: 119px; left: 368px; width: 800px; height: 400px; z-index: 1005;">
<tbody>
   <tr>
      <td style="width:800px;height:400px;" class="dialogbox" id="td_dialog_promptsDlg" onresize="_CWprompts.DialogBoxWidget_resizeIframeCB('promptsDlg',this)" valign="top">
         <table class="dlgBox2" width="100%" border="0" cellspacing="0" cellpadding="0">
<tbody>
   <tr>
      <td height="0" valign="top">
         <table style="height:26" class="dlgTitle" width="100%" border="0" cellspacing="0" cellpadding="0">
            <tbody>
               <tr valign="top" style="height:26px">
                  <td onselectstart="return false" ondragstart="return false" onmousedown="_CWprompts.DialogBoxWidget_down(event,'promptsDlg',this,false);return false;" style="cursor:move;padding-left:10px;" width="100%" valign="middle" align="left">
                     <nobr>
                        <span id="ariaLabelledBy_promptsDlg" class="titlezone">Prompts</span>
                     </nobr>
                  </td>
                  <td class="dlgCloseArea" align="left" valign="middle">
                     <table border="0" cellspacing="0" cellpadding="0">
                        <tbody>
                           <tr style="height:26px">
                              <td valign="middle" align="left" style="padding-right:4px;">
                                 <div id="helpIcon_promptsDlg" "="" title="Help Contents" class="imo" style="width:16px;height:16px;background-image:url('images/main/galleries/icon16x16gallery1b.png');background-position:0px -480px;"></div>
                              </td>
                              <td style="padding-right:10px">
                                 <div id="dialogClose_promptsDlg" class="dlgCloseBtn" title="Close window"></div>
                              </td>
                           </tr>
                        </tbody>
                     </table>
                  </td>
               </tr>
            </tbody>
         </table>
      </td>
   </tr>
```

I am getting no such alert exception. Can someone please help me out with this?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Welcome to Stackoverflow! Please provide a [Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) of what you've tried so far so we can reproduce your issue.

Comment: @Ayisha Update the question with the relevant HTML

Comment: it's probably not a real alert, but a modal div. In that case, just work with it as with any other element on the page